# Problems with Breakpoints to run class library from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, breakpoints

I have two projects, A and B. In project A (which is a console application) I refer to B (which is an application library) to use classes that I have there. When trying to do debug in B I realized that I jumped when I gave F11 and wanting to put a break point in the method of project B I got this message

The breakpoint will not be activated currently. No symbol can be loaded for this document.

I was looking for the whole morning and I have not found the solution. I already checked that the project is in debug mode as mentioned in most of the pages that visit all that is fine

Comment: Have you checked that the project is including the pdb files in the ouput?

Comment: I read something about the .pdb, but I can not understand this. Should be the project .pdb b, for example ProjectB.pdb inside projectA.app/bin/debug (?)

Comment: Right click the on the project.  Then click on Properties.  Then go to the Build tab.  At the bottom o the Build screen there is a button called Advanced; click on it.  It will show you 2 sections. The bottom one says Output.  In there the debugging information should be Full.  Please let me know what it says and we can take it from there.

Comment: Both projects should be outputting the debug information.

Comment: I checked both projects as you indicated and both have selected the option <debugging info: "full">

Comment: So Project A is a Console Application and Project B is a Class Library?

Comment: Also check that Define DEBUG constant is checked in the Build page.  Also the Define TRACE constant should be checked.

Comment: Check your bin\debug to make sure the pdb files are in there

Comment: Yes, effectively. 
Even the console application is executing the code of the class library. I'm just throwing an error when instantiating a class, but I can not see exactly what happens because it does not allow me to debug it

Comment: Have you placed any of these in the GAC?

Comment: No, I have not placed any in the GAC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192978/discussion-between-darkonekt-and-arnell-vasquez-c).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to the conversation with the user **darkonket**.

The problem was that I needed to add to the solution a third project which was indispensable so that the library of classes could be debugged.